# Select Element inside Form not working in JQuery

Tags: jquery

I have the following HTML form:

```
<div id="main">
  <form Id="search-form" action="/ViewRecord/AllRecord" method="post">
    <div>
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Search</legend>
           <p>
                <label for="username">Staff name</label>
                <input id="username" name="username" type="text" value="" />
                <label for="softype"> software type</label>

                <input type="submit" value="Search" />
            </p>
        </fieldset>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

And I want to show an `alert` box when the `username` field is clicked. This is my JQuery code:

```
$(function() {
$("#username").click(function() {
        $.getJSON("ViewRecord/GetSoftwareChoice", {},
    function(data) {
        alert(data);
    });
    });
});
```

For certain reason the `Click` is never fired; anything I did wrong?

Comment: the form tag is closed ?

Comment: Have you tried putting the alert outside the $.getJSON? The $.getJSON propably fails so you don't see your alert.

Comment: @haim, yes,form tag is closed. I edited the question

Comment: another thing why not use $(document).ready(function(){}
?

Comment: haim: $(function() { ... }); is shorthand for $(document).ready(function() { ... });

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is correct and the event should be fired. Probably the problem is with AJAX call. Put an alert before the ajax call to make sure that this is indeed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You might want the [`focus`](http://www.w3schools.com/HTMLDOM/met_text_focus.asp) event instead, as `click` will only fire if you explicitly click on the element:

```
$(function() {
    $("#username").focus(function() {
        $.getJSON("ViewRecord/GetSoftwareChoice", {}, function(data) {
            alert(data);
        });
    });
});
```

Other than that, you might want to look in [Firebug](http://www.getfirebug.com) to make sure the request is completing successfully. Or, even better, you could use the lower-level `$.ajax` call to see if the request is not completing:

```
$(function() {
    $("#username").focus(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'ViewRecord/GetSoftwareChoice',
            dataType: 'json',
            type: 'GET',
            success: function(data) { alert(data); },
            error: function() { alert('something went wrong!'); }
        });
    });
});
```