# JQuery Ajax call gives 404 'Resource Not Found' Error but normal URL call is fine

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a weird problem when using JQuery call in my ASP.NET MVC project. I found that the Ajax call gives 404 ( resource not found error). But when I use the usual URL GET call, I can successfully call the server without any problem. Any idea why this is so?

This my ASP.NET MVC code

```
public class ViewRecordController: Controller
{
  public JSONResult GetSoftwareChoice(string username)
  {
     return Json(username);
  }
}
```

This is my JQuery code:

```
$(function() {
$("#username").click(function() {
        $.getJSON("ViewRecord/GetSoftwareChoice", {username:'123'},
    function(data) {
        alert(data);
    });
    });
});
```

The above JQuery gives me a 404 error. Apparently the `ViewRecord/GetSoftwareChoice` is not found on server, as far as the AJAX call is concerned.

But if I type this in my web browser:

```
http://myapp/ViewRecord/GetSoftwareChoice?username=123
```

then there is no problem.

This is very weird, indeed.

Just in case if you are interested, this is my route:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapRoute(
        "Default",                                              // Route name
        "{controller}/{action}/{id}",                           // URL with parameters
        new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "" }  // Parameter defaults
    );

}
```

Edit: I step into my code, and found that the URL call is `ViewRecord/GetSoftwareChoice?username=123`.

Related question: [Select Element inside Form not working in JQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1000246/select-element-inside-form-not-working-in-jquery)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I fix this problem by using FireBug to show me the request that was generated by JQuery. To my amazement, the url generated is

```
http://localhost/ViewRecord/ViewRecord/GetSoftwareChoice?username=123
```

for the JSON call:

```
$(function() {
$("#username").click(function() {
        $.getJSON("ViewRecord/GetSoftwareChoice", {username:'123'},
    function(data) {
        alert(data);
    });
    });
});
```

So I just have to change the `$.getJSON` line to

```
$.getJSON("GetSoftwareChoice", {username:'123'},
```

Alternatively, use the forward slash:

```
 $.getJSON("/ViewRecord/GetSoftwareChoice", {username:'123'},
```

Comment: .... or to "/ViewRecord/GetSoftwareChoice". the leading slash means an absolute path, even if you don't include the hostname

Comment: Thanks, Javier. I included your response in my answer.

Comment: I think Johhny G (and Jarrod in the comments) already implied this answer.

Answer (score 8):

Instead of hard-coding the URL, you might want to try a UrlHelper:

```
$(function() {
    $("#username").click(function() {
        var url = '<%= UrlHelper.Action("GetSoftwareChoice", "ViewRecord") %>';
        $.getJSON(url, {username: '123'}, function(data) {
            alert(data);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Exactly - I'm thinking that it's also an issue with the jQuery fetch url being relative to the current path, instead of from the app root.

Comment: Also, +1 for using FireBug and showing us the FireBug console results.

Comment: I don't think UrlHelper works in Javascript ( I have tested it)... are you sure it works?

Comment: It wouldn't work in a separate .js file, but it would work inside a <script> tag in an aspx/ascx file.

Comment: Gosh... that's too bad a limitation. I always keep my javascript in a separate .js file, for easier reading..

Comment: If you keep it in a separate file then you need to take notice of what Johnny G was REALLY saying and what Jarrod pointed out - the url you have ("ViewRecord/GetSoftwareChoice") is a relative path and probably not what you want - you need to change it to the correct relative path or make it an absolute path.

Comment: And... in Razor syntax, it would be:

`'@Url.Action("SearchBranch", "Referral")'`

Whatch those single quotes!  They have to be there.

Comment: I was able to use Url.Content() inside a manually-created <a>'s href for my purposes.

Answer (score 4):

```
$(function() {
    $("#username").click(function() {
        $.getJSON('<%= Url.Action("GetSoftwareChoice", "ViewRecord")%>',{username: '123'}, function(data) {
            alert(data);
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Firefox Firebug add on, and watch what request gets made by Jquery...

Is it possible that the page that this Jquery runs in is in a subdirectory, in which case the request will not be relative root as the http://myapp/ "typed in" url is?

Also, I am guessing the code you specified above is not actually the code you are using (which is completely reasonable, I rairly post code as-is).  Because

```
$.getJSON("ViewRecord/GetSoftwareChoice", {username='123'},
```

the = sign between username and '123' is invalid JS as far as I know.  So I'm betting there is some goofy detail in the the real code that is causing the problem.

Comment: I am using ASP.NET MVC, so there is no problem of request will not be relative root as the http://myapp/ "typed in" url is.

Comment: I am also using ASP.NET MVC and originally had my ajax path set as "/Controller/Action", but due to this answer and @Javier's comment on Graviton's own answer about the forward slash being an absolute path, I found out that this was not a relative path when the app was pushed to the server which does bury the app in a couple of subdirectory layers that is different from my local environment.  The correct solution for me was to have a completely relative path that contained the controller and action such as var url = "Controller/Action";

Answer (score 1):

Replace the equal sign with a colon:

```
$(function() {
$("#username").click(function() {
        $.getJSON("ViewRecord/GetSoftwareChoice", {username:'123'},
    function(data) {
        alert(data);
    });
    });
});
```

Comment: Sorry! It's a typo in my question. I am using {username:'123'} in my code but accidentally typed {username='123'}

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same problem.  After using Firebug as Graviton had done, I saw that my path was wonky so I changed it to just the name of my action.  `Get_OrderLine` is the name of my action in my controller.  `inv_item_id` is the parameter passed to the controller action.

```
// Update OrderLine data by returning a JSON result
$('#itemsddl').click(function (e) {
    var selectedItem = $(this).val();
    var actionURL = "Get_OrderLine";
    var d = "inv_item_id=" + selectedItem;
    var uom = $('#uom');
    var size = $('#size');
    var unitLbs = $('#unitLbs');
    var totalLbs = $('#totalLbs');
    var shipName = $('#shipName');
    var hazardClass = $('#hazardClass');
    var unnaNo = $('#unnaNo');
    var packingGroup = $('#packingGroup');
    var placard = $('#placard');
    var ergNo = $('#ergNo');
    $.ajax({
        cache: false,
        type: 'GET',
        url: actionURL, 
        data: d,
        datatype: JSON,
        success: function (data) {
            uom.val(data.uom);
            size.val(data.size);
            unitLbs.val(data.unitLbs);
            totalLbs.val(data.totalLbs);
            shipName.val(data.shipName);
            hazardClass.val(data.hazardClass);
            unnaNo.val(data.unnaNo);
            packingGroup.val(data.packingGroup);
            placard.val(data.placard);
            ergNo.val(data.ergNo);
        },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            alert('Failed to query item - ' + thrownError + "\n" + "Full details: " + xhr.responseText);
        }
    });
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

This is my action which returns a JSON result to my jQuery.  The jQuery function then handles mapping from JSON to HTML.  Not very pretty, but it works.

```
public ActionResult Get_OrderLine(int? inv_item_id)
{
    HazmatInfoItem item = new HazmatInfoItem();
    item.itemId = "0";
    item.size = "0";
    item.unitLbs = 0;
    item.qty = 0;
    item.totalLbs = item.qty * item.unitLbs;
    item.shipName = "";
    item.hazardClass = "";
    item.unnaNo = "";
    item.packingGroup = "";
    item.placard = "";
    item.ergNo = "";

    var items = from i in hazmatRepository.GetAllItems()
                select i;

    // Get item details
    items = items.Where(i => i.INV_ITEM_ID.Contains(inv_item_id.ToString()));

    foreach (var i in items)
    {
        item.uom = i.UNIT_MEASURE_STD;
        item.size = i.INV_ITEM_SIZE;
        item.unitLbs = 1;
        item.totalLbs = item.unitLbs * item.qty;
        item.shipName = i.PAG_SHIPPING_NAME;
        item.hazardClass = i.HAZ_CLASS_CD;
        item.unnaNo = i.MSDS_ID;
        item.packingGroup = i.PACKING_CD;
        item.placard = i.PAG_PLACARD_TYPE;
    }

    return Json(item, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

I had originally added a new route to try to handle this, but commented it out to allow the default routing.

Hopefully these solutions can help someone else who has had a similar problem when trying to use .ajax with jQuery and MVC.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take a look at stackoverflow.com/about to see the format of helpful answers! The code bits here are extremely long and are unlikely to be read by someone (especially with how many other answers there are). If you want to help someone who comes across this in the future, consider shortening your code bits to the ~5-10 lines from your code that actually solve this issue!

Answer (score 0):

Old function :

```
function Chart() {

    var url = "../Home/Pie/";
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        data: {},
        cache: false,
        type: "POST",
        success: function (data) {
            var chartData = data;
            createChart(chartData);
            $(document).bind("kendo:skinChange", createChart);
        },
        error: function (xhr, status, error) {
            $('#alertdialog').html(status);
            $('#alertdialog').dialog('open');
            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

**Answers :**
**var url = "Home/Pie/**"; 
Removed ../ from url