# JQuery Ajax call gets resolved to the current Controller Folder, Instead of root Folder

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I think I found something very weird in JQuery and ASP.NET MVC.

As mentioned in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1004899/jquery-ajax-call-gives-404-resource-not-found-error-but-normal-url-call-is-fine), I have the following JQuery code:

```
$(function () {
    $("#username").click(function () {
        $.getJSON("ViewRecord/GetSoftwareChoice", { username: '123' },
            function (data) {
                alert(data);
            });
    });
});
```

`ViewRecord` is the controller and `GetSoftwareChoice` is the action method. But the URl generated for this is

```
http://localhost/ViewRecord/ViewRecord/GetSoftwareChoice?username=123
```

Pretty amazing, isn't it?

Why this is the case?

This is my route:

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

routes.MapRoute(
    "Default",                                              // Route name
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}",                           // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "" }  // Parameter defaults
);
```

Comment: They gave you the answer to this in your previous question.  Why ask a new one?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

without a leading slash, the URL's path is a local path and it's resolved relative to the page's path.  just like any other URL that you might put into your HTML.

Answer (score 4):

Try using this as your URL:

```
 $.getJSON("/ViewRecord/GetSoftwareChoice", // etc
```

Note the prefixed forward slash.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery doesn't know anything about MVC, controllers, or actions.  You're telling it: "here is a relative URL - take the URL of the current page and append the relative URL to it."  You probably want to say something like:

```
var newURL = "http://" + document.domain + "/ViewRecord/GetSoftwareChoice";
```