# How do I call a controller method from JQuery?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, jquery

I have ajax code for asp.net (non-mvc) to call to a webMethod to get additional data from the server for a request. But I can't seem to figure out the url to give my JQuery in MVC.

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
function SubmitAjax(url, message, successFunc, errorFunc) {
    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:url,
        data:message,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success:successFunc,
        error:errorFunc
        });

};
```

I don't want to pass the entire list of related data to a select list to every person that arrives at the page, as not all will need this functionality. So I'd like to call a controller or webmethod via JQuery, but can't seem to find out how to address the URL in MVC.

I noticed this post: 
[JQuery Ajax call gets resolved to the current Controller Folder, Instead of root Folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1005122/jquery-ajax-call-gets-resolved-to-the-current-controller-folder-instead-of-root)

is $.getJson an mvc method? is this a good solution for my use case? I only need to return a string url, or an empty string if what i'm looking for is not found. Do I need to include a  for the $.getJSon method? is that part of MVC or part of JQuery? Is the leading slash going to point to Application root or server root?

Comment: MVC is not a specific library with actual function names. It is a design *pattern*... Unless Microsoft actually named the framework that... which they might, come to think of it. Originality isn't their strong suit. (Googling that...) - But on the point... `$.getJson` is a jQuery function to fetch JSON data via AJAX requests. Has nothing specific to do with .Net.

Comment: A url is always a url. It doesn't work any differently in asp.net mvc.

Comment: @Atli i'm not sure which part you are referring to, in the top I was referring to Asp.net MVC, at the bottom I was referring to the Asp.net MVC javascripts that come bundled.

Comment: @Mattias your url is different in MVC based on what you are calling, content, a webMethod, or if there's a way... a controller action directly that's not a webMethod.

Comment: @Maslow No, a url is always the same thing for the browser. You just have a framework that handles it a little bit differently. The browser doesn't know if you are using asp.net mvc or any other framework. It just calls a url and expect a result of some kind. Asp.net mvc isn't magic and has nothing to do with the browser. Webmethod is nothing the browser knows anything about. It just except a result from that url.

Comment: @Mattias I understand that. Nowhere in my post did I mention a browser so I'm not sure what you were trying to say.

Comment: @Maslow. Ok, so they did apparently just call it "ASP.Net MVC" *(/sigh... Can you blame me for being confused? xD)* - My point was that "MVC" is not specific to either ASP.Net nor anything related to it. It is a general design pattern, used very widely. - And it has nothing to do with jQuery or it's AJAX functions (such as `$.getJson`) either. - Sorry I can't be of more use than that.

Comment: @Maslow What I'm saying is pretty much the answer to your question. Jquery has nothing to do with the server framework you use. Therefore you use it exactly like you would if you where using webforms (for example) as server side framework.

Comment: @Atli, no problem, thanks for trying.
@Mattias - well so far the error message my Ajax call gets back is Not Found. Ah..we have progress.. I removed the [WebMethod] tag, and reduced the url to just CheckForInstaller and now I get InternalServerError.

Comment: @Maslow The WebMethod attribute is only a webforms thing that is used to route a incoming url to a specific method. That isn't needed in asp.net mvc as you already have the routing library that routes all incoming url's to the right method (action).

Comment: @Mattias thanks, any idea on what the Internal Server Error is or how to diagnose it?

Comment: @Maslow Just start the debugger and you will see the error. If the action you are trying to call doesn't get hit, then your url is wrong. See my answer for explanation on how url's work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the webMethod Tag on the controller, that was needed or helpful in asp.net, but not in asp.net mvc

Answer (score 3):

Try this post:
[Basic AJAX example with ASP.NET MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/764965/basic-ajax-example-with-asp-net-mvc/765974#765974)

or this one:
[How to get the Json object for drop down?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/746815/how-to-get-the-json-object-for-drop-down/748446#748446)

They should give you some pointers.

In essence, $.getJson is a jQuery method, not an MVC one, but use want to use that in combination with your MVC controller returning a Json result.

Comment: @Johannes thanks this is my url: `"Ticket/CheckForInstaller"` but I get not found..my controller class is `TicketController` the method is ` [WebMethod]
        public ContentResult CheckForInstaller(int appId)` but they aren't lining up.

Comment: @Maslow You need to supply appropriate param for your action. Your action is "CheckForInstaller" and it requires "appId". If this is registered in your route, you can simply call "Ticket/CheckForInstaller/1" ("1" is just an example of appId). If not registered, should be like this: "Ticket/CheckForInstaller?appId=1"

Comment: in the example he is using POST, so "appId" should be a post parameter (not visible in the url).

Answer (score 2):

Well, my guess is that you are having trouble with how url's are constructed. If you don't have a slash before the url it will be relative to your current url. So if the current url is: `/Home/Index` and you have a link like this: `<a href="Ticket/CheckForInstaller">Text</a>` then that link will point to the following url: `/Home/Index/Ticket/CheckForInstaller`. This is always the behavior in the browser. The same thing happens if you have a page in a folder in a webforms application. There is nothing different with a asp.net mvc url then with any other web framework. The url you want is probably this one: `/Ticket/CheckForInstaller`.

The asp.net mvc framework does, however, supply you with helpers so that you don't have to hard code any url. You can do that like this:

```
<%=Url.Action("Ticket", "CheckForInstaller")%>
```

But the only thing this will do is find the appropriate url that points to that action ("/Ticket/CheckForInstaller", depending on your routes) and write it out.

Answer (score 1):

You can use $.getJSON(url,[data],[callback(data)]) where data is your returned json data object.

Alternatively you can use $.post(url,[data],[callback(data)]) where data is you returened string /  data object.

url : it is the relative url to your controller/action/script which returns json/data back.

The above are jquery methods and you shoul be able to use if you have included jquery js file.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I've been doing lately, and it's been working fine.

1. Get the root path and store it in a hidden input (replace [ with <)

   [input id="urlBase" type="hidden" value="<%= Url.Content("~") %>" />
2. Get the value of that input and store it in js (using jquery in this case)

   _urlBase = $("#urlBase").val();
3. Use that variable to call controllers

   $.ajax({ type: "GET", url: _urlBase + "Controller/Action", dataType: "json" });