# MVC 4 Google Charts from SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, google-visualization

I'm playing about with MVC 4 using C#, ASP.NET and Razor. I have set up the basic CRUD functionality using MS SQL Server and it all works fine.

I would now like to display that data in graphical format. I'm loving the Google charts API and have implemented charts using the static array examples with no worries.

The problem I am having now is that I can't seem to find many tutorials/links that explain how to display my MS SQL Data within Google Charts in an MVC-ish way.

Comment: KendoUIDataViz is seamless. However, this may be a no go for you.

Comment: I meant www.http://demos.kendoui.com/dataviz/overview/index.html The have MVC and MVVC type patterns. They do create for client side. But I am not sure that is what you want.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure I fully understand what you are trying to achieve.

You want to return SQL data and then display this in a graph in the view?

If so could take the following approach:

1. Return data from database in some Data access layer
2. Load the data into a model. These two task could be done with Entity framework
3. Return the data from the controller in a JSONResult
4. In the view call the controller(you could also use a webapi) using Ajax.
5. Bind result to graph in Ajax callback.

See the question below for more details.

[How do I call a controller method from JQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2238658/how-do-i-call-a-controller-method-from-jquery)