# Google Visualization chart with ASP.NET

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, visual-studio-2012, google-visualization

I am trying to develop an online monitoring system. For that I want to use the `Google Visualization  API`. 
The data for preparing chart for the monitoring I am using `PIC 32` platform. I am storing my data into `SQL Server 2012` database.

Now What I want to do is that I want to populate a motion chart which updates after some time(user specified). But I am not getting any reference how to club `SQL Server` with google Visualization chart.
So anything to start with ?

Comment: So the thing is I need to create a JSON file. So how do I create a JSON in asp.net. As the example shown in goolge is for .php not for asp. so can any tell me how to create a JSON file?

Comment: You don't want to create a JSON file (that just adds an unnecessary step to the process).  You want to create a service that queries your database and returns a JSON representation of a (Google Visualization API) DataTable object.  You can then write an AJAX request in javascript to call the service and retrieve the JSON.  There's a 3rd-party library for .Net applications that implements much of the server-side code that might be useful to you: http://code.google.com/p/bortosky-google-visualization/wiki/ReadMe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest creating a new project for some WebAPIs

Then follow this recently answered question.

[MVC 4 Google Charts from SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19532032/mvc-4-google-charts-from-sql-server/19535161#19535161)

Answer (score 0):

This has been done for you; look on code.google.com or codeplex.com.  Just download one of the many implementations.  I authored one that creates usercontrols for each and can be simply dragged into the project.

http://code.google.com/p/googlevisualizationsdotnet/