# Resource can not be found error in calling Webservice by Ajax

Tags: jquery, .net, ajax, web-services

I have created a .net Webservice by name `multiOptionService.asmx` .In this Webservice i have created a WebMethod by name `public  string getCallType()`.Now in my jquery file i am trying to call by ajax using below code..

```
function showCallTypeDialogueBox() {
var calloutput = null;
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'multiOptionService.asmx/getCallType',
    async: false,
    dataType: "text",
    success: function (data) {     
        alert(data);
        }
    }
});
```

Now when i am trying to call the function i am getting `The resource cannot be found.` error in firebug of firfox.
Please help me in telling where i am going wrong and correct me..
Thanks..

Comment: error:function(a,b,er){alert(er) } can you use this method? because this one show particular ajax call service response error

Comment: @Angu I am getting error in firebug of firefox ..Can you tell me whether my URL calling is correct or not because i am getting error as resource not found

Comment: var url = '<%= UrlHelper.Action("actionname", "controllername") %>'; use it

Comment: use this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1004899/jquery-ajax-call-gives-404-resource-not-found-error-but-normal-url-call-is-fin