# jquery datatable ajax url duplicates part of the url path

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring-boot, web-deployment

I have a spring boot web application that is working fine on my local, now while deploying to the server I was having below issues:

**link to other pages:**

On my local the below works fine:

```
<a class="dropdown-item" href="/admin/manage-users">Users</a>
```

But while deploying to the server the url to work is supposed to be like: `http://website.com/projectname/admin/manage-users` but it was showing as: `http://website.com/admin/manage-users` giving me 404 not found error. To fix that I had to use either of the below:

Remove the leading slash:

```
<a class="dropdown-item" href="admin/manage-users">Users</a>
```

or use thymeleaf context-relative URLs:

```
<a class="dropdown-item" th:href="@{/admin/manage-users}">Users</a>
```

**Ajax calls:**

I was trying the same approach with ajax calls, but in this case it didn't work. I have a datatable as below which is working fine on my local:

```
var t_users = $("#tbl_users").DataTable({
    "ajax": {
        "url": "/admin/get-users",
        "type": "GET",
        "dataSrc": ""
    }, ...
```

But on the server is giving me the same 404 not found error because `projectname` was missing from the url, so I tried removing the leading slash and now I'm getting a datatables ajax error because in the url `admin` is showing twice: `.../admin/admin/manage-users` so to fix that I found out from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1005100/808891) I need to remove `admin` from the url as below:

```
var t_users = $("#tbl_users").DataTable({
    "ajax": {
        "url": "get-users",
        "type": "GET",
        "dataSrc": ""
    },
```

Is there any other way to make this work using `admin/get-users` in the url to avoid confusions?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to take a dynamic approach to avoid these issues in ajax calls:

1. Prepare context url dynamically in one js file - url.js

```js
    var appHost = window.location.host;
    var appProtocol = window.location.protocol
    var pathArray = window.location.pathname.split('/');
    var context = pathArray[1];

    var contextUrl = appProtocol +"//"+ appHost +"/"+ context;
```

2. use this context url with api and prepare every url in ajax:

```js
var url = contextUrl + "/admin/get-users" ;

var t_users = $("#tbl_users").DataTable({
    "ajax": {
        "url": url,
        "type": "GET",
        "dataSrc": ""
    }, ...
```

Comment: `admin` is coming twice with this approach this is on my local, `contextUrl` already has `admin` in the path